# Convergence of harmonic oscillator to the free particle and the issue of asymptotic freedom in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, differential-equations

For any $\epsilon >0$, consider the following harmonic oscillator with $m= \hbar =1$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x,t)= -\frac{1}{2}\Delta \psi+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}x^2 \psi
\end{equation}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t$ is time.

Then, I wonder if solutions of the above Schrodinger equation converge to the [free particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_particle) as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

If they converge, may I understand this as an example of [asymptotic freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_freedom#:%7E:text=In%20quantum%20field%20theory%2C%20asymptotic,the%20corresponding%20length%20scale%20decreases.)?

Could anyone please provide some insight?

Comment: Sounds a little dubious. The harmonic oscillator always has zero average momentum whereas the free particle is not constrained that way. Am I overlooking something? Maybe it converges to a free particle in a box in some sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the spectrum of the Hamilton operator changes discontinuously from a pure point spectrum for $\epsilon >0$ to a purely continuous spectrum ($\mathbb{R}^+$) for $\epsilon =0$.

Comment: Ok. So, does it make sense to say that the harmonic oscillator is NOT asymptotically free?

Comment: @Keith Asymptotic freedom in relativistic quantum field theories is related  to the negative sign of the beta function in nonabelian gauge theories (provided there are not too "many" matter fields present). This phenomenon is completely unrelated to your question in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: Well, it means that an interacting theory approaches free theory in the UV limit. Negative sign of the beta function is just an equivalent condition of this property.

Comment: In the above case, $\epsilon$ is proportional to the the angular frequency and thus the energy. So, $\epsilon \to 0^+$ does not look like UV limit... That is why I am confused in this case. At least, you said that convergence to the free particle fails in the limit..